# nesting three if statements

Tags: c#, if-statement

I would like to check if the condition "_Email" is met the first time and pass the result to the next if statement for another check and then again after that. If _Email is null, I want it to be an empty string for the last check.

Here is the code

```
    private string _Email;
    public string Email
    {
        get
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_Email))
            {
                _Email = GetEmailAddress();
            }
            else if (_Email.IsEmptyOrNull())
            {
                _Email = User.Current.Preference("Email");
            }
            else if (_Email.IsEmptyOrNull())
            {
                _Email = "";
            }
            return _Email;
        }
    }
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: What is this `IsEmptyOrNull` ? I assume you mean `string.IsNullOrEmpty`? You can't call a function on an object (`_Email`) if the object is null. You will get a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: @BradleyDotNET First, I think the "nonsense" part is what he's asking about (it's because he should be using `if` not `else if`) and second, where is their site effects? He's manipulating a backing property which doesn't seem unacceptable to me?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET no, it's not. It makes perfectly good sense, they should just be if, not else if's. If it's null, try to assign it. If it's still null, try to pull from somewhere else. if STILL null, set to empty. In no way are the conditions nonsense. They are MEANT to be the same.

Answer (score 4):

you need to remove the `else` in your code because only the first if clause where the condition is met will be executed

and `IsNullOrEmpty` is a static method on the `String` class. Use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` instead of `_Email.IsNullOrEmpty`. (I get a compiler error when I try to do it like `_Email.IsNullOrEmpty`)

```
private string _Email;
public string Email
{
    get
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_Email))
        {
            _Email = GetEmailAddress();
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_Email))
        {
            _Email = User.Current.Preference("Email");
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_Email))
        {
            _Email = "";
        }
        return _Email;
    }
}
```

and I would recommend moving your code into an method called something like `GetEmail` to reduce your code in your property (it gets ugly in my opinion)

Comment: The conditions are not the same, since _Email can change between one if and the next.

Comment: but if the first try doesn't return a string then maybe the second or the thirth. I think thats the idea?